# Access JSON position in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js

I have a JSON string in this format:

```
[
   {
      "Origin":{
         "FtpHost":"info",
         "FtpFolder":"info",
         "FtpUser":"info",
         "FtpPassword":"info",
         "FtpInsideFolder":"info",
         "Pattern":"info"
      },
      "Destination":{
         "FtpHost":"info",
         "FtpFolder":"info",
         "FtpUser":"info",
         "FtpPassword":"info",
         "FtpInsideFolder":"info"
      },
      "CustomFolderName":"Conad",
      "OperationTraverseType":"RootOnly"
   }
]
```

To pick up the JSON I wrote this in Node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = fs.readFileSync('Operations.json', 'utf8');
```

I'm wondering, how I can access for example : "***Destination***" fields?

Comment: obj[0].Destination or obj[0]["Destination"]

Comment: it says undefined

Comment: You can `require` directly the JSON and access it as a normal Array/Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must parse this to JSON. because fs.readFile returns string

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = fs.readFileSync('Operations.json', 'utf8');
obj = JSON.parse(obj)

var Destination = obj[0].Destination
// or
var Destination = obj[0]["Destination"]
```

> Edit (as said Diego)

You can also directly require json file

```
var obj = require('somejsonfile.json');
var Destination = obj[0]. Destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to simply `parse` the read data. Something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = fs.readFileSync('Operations.json', 'utf8').toString();
obj = JSON.parse(obj)
console.log(obj[0].Destination)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like var myjson = JSON.parse(obj) or obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Operations.json', 'utf8')) and then access it like obj[0]["Destination"]["FIELD"] where FIELD - represents the "Destination" object field you want